# Google Contacts Api -> Which contacts were deleted?

Tags: php, xml, synchronization, gmail

I am parsing contacts from Gmail, and creating a sync functionality with my product. 
But on my script i'm having a hard time determining which contacts get 'deleted' from gmail.

EXAMPLE:
If I have **John Doe** in my Application, along with Gmail... (and they are synced with the gmailId). Later on down the road, if the user **DELETES the contact John Doe**, and I run my SYNC, ***how do I determine that the contact was deleted?***

I need to know where to throw a *trigger to delete* the same contact within my database. I currently have this to obtain information on each contact sent through.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($entry->getXML());
$obj = new stdClass;

//    EDIT LINK
$obj->gmailUrl   = rawurlencode($entry->id);                
$obj->delete     =  (string) $xml->groupMembershipInfo['deleted'];

//    FIRST Name
$obj->firstName  = (string) $xml->name->givenName;
```

Previous in my code i'm also query google with these extra params.

```
$query->setParam('updated-min', $updatedMin);
$query->setParam('showdeleted', 'true');
$query->setParam('requirealldeleted', 'true');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that Google adds an empty XML Tag called Deleted when a contact is deleted.

Something like this.

```
if(isset($xml->deleted)) { $deleted = "true"; } else { $deleted = NULL; } 
$obj->delete = $deleted;
```

Although Adrian's solution would work, I felt that wasn't the best solution as I felt Google must to have an answer for this rather than checking to see if a contact was available every day.

Comment: This however will only be caught if the item was deleted within last 30 days per google's documentation.

Comment: True... For syncing it should be fine, but for that initial blast might be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about any particular hooks, nor can I see an obvious `deleted` field, but here is another way to solve the problem...

When you do your full sync, or single item updates, if a particular contact is no longer returned, then you can mark it as deleted.  Note, this would only work if you keep `showdeleted` as `false`.

Example...

```
$local = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
```

You run a full sync...

```
$remote = array(, 1, 3, 5, 9);
```

Comparing the two arrays will show that 7 has been deleted.  Similarly, if you are synchronizing a single item, if it doesn't return anything you can assume its deleted.